# Accessing android Marketplace from desktop android capable phones in office

Tags: google-play-store

We have some android capable desktop IP phones in our office, is there an app that i can download to my phone that will allow it to access the Android marketplace. There is currently no way to access the marketplace, we have to manually download the apps on a card and upload them to the phone.

Any ideas would help, thanks.

UPDATE: I know how to download and install apps to the devices, i am looking for an app that will allow me to access the marketplace from the desk phones so i dont have to manually install via an SD card.

I searched the forums and wasnt able to find the answer I wanted.

Comment: And exactly that's what the referred question is about: how to install Google Play. In case you don't know: Google Play is an app that will allow you to access the "marketplace" using the same name :) If it's not *that* marketplace you want to access, take a look at e.g. [F-Droid](http://f-droid.org/), the [Amazon Appstore](https://www.amazon.de/gp/feature.html?docId=1000644903), or the [AndroidPIT App Center](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/market/app-center).